# How to render html in web-mode?

Tags: html, web-mode

I'm using web-mode within emacs to edit an html file, in html-mode I can use `C-c C-v` to render html, it opens the file straight to Firefox.

How I do that with web-mode?

Thanks a lot,

P.S : Using emacs 26.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find out what `C-c C-v` does by pressing `F1 k C-c C-v` in a `html-mode` buffer:

> C-c C-v runs the command browse-url-of-buffer (found in
>   html-mode-map), which is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp
>   function in ‘browse-url.el’.

That command can be bound in the appropriate `web-mode` keymap, aptly named `web-mode-map`:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'web-mode
  (define-key web-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-v") 'browse-url-of-buffer))
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer ! I added ``:bind ("C-c C-v" . browse-url-of-buffer)`` to my ``use-package`` and it works well.